# Will changing IIS7 home directory cause restart or app pool recycle?

Tags: iis, iis-7, application-pool

If I change the Home Directory for an IIS 7 website, will this cause either of the following?

- The application pool to restart
- The app domain to recycle

This question has been [asked for IIS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574597/will-a-change-to-the-iis-home-directory-path-trigger-a-restart/1575820) but I am curious to see if it has changed in IIS 7 or 7.5.